Laravel 419 Page Expired, works on local
I recently added a new feature to my website so that admins are able to view and delete files in storage/app/public/files/uploads
This feature works fine in my local copy but on the live server I keep getting a 419 page expired. I searched around the web and found that the most likely cause is a missing @csrf at the start of my form but I already have this in my code.
<form method="POST" action="{{route('dashboard.uploaddelete', $file)}}">
    @csrf
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p class="font-weight-bold">Are you sure you wish to delete {{$file}}? This action is irreversible!</p>
        <input type="hidden" name="filename" value="{{$file}}">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</form>

I have tried clearing artisan cache, routes, views and config but no luck.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

It can be a list of factors. Are the .env values correctly set in live server ? File/Directory permissions ? $file value is sent with the body and header request, maybe you need only one.

@AntonioGocaj Everything is set correctly, including permissions. I use the same method for something else that's also in the storage directory. Tried both with only header and only body and still getting 419

@Colem run the command php artisan key:generate on the server

@N69S The server was already up for a long time before I introduced this feature. Running that command will likely break things for all users

This solution has worked for me:
Open the file config/session.php and made some changes:
update the values:
'lifetime' => 120, 
'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),
'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),

Also check the storage/  folder have an proper permission.
After that open the terminal and run those commands:
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:clear


I can't for the life of my clear cache anymore. One of the folders in the framework/data folder has for some reason decided to not give write access to group and I can't manualy delete it. I don't have root permission either unfortunately.

Mostly 419 error is thrown when the csrf token is being mismatched.

Firstly, try using the webstie in the incognito window, if it worked
then the issue is with the cache memories.

You can manually view the csrf token: {{ csrf_token() }} and check
whether it matches with the token saved in the session.

You can increase the life time of the session in config/session.php  file by changing the lifetime value or change it in the .env file by using this      SESSION_LIFETIME=120

Check both the form and your site uses HTTPS protocol

Check .env config, make sure you have both SESSION_DOMAIN and APP_URL
are same


If you are using AJAX call, then you need to pass the csrf token in the header.

Add an meta tag to save the csrf token in it


< meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">


Then in your ajax, add the header


headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN':
$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')}

You can try this method but it is not recommended:
If you want to turn off the CSRF protection for a specific route in Laravel, you need to add the below lines in the app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCrsfToken.php file
//add an array of Routes to skip CSRF check
private $exceptUrls = ['controller/route1', 'controller/route2'];
//modify this function
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
//add this condition foreach($this->exceptUrls as $route) {
if ($request->is($route)) {
  return $next($request);
}
}
return parent::handle($request, $next);
}

refer https://hackr.io/blog/top-laravel-interview-questions-and-answers
32nd question.

Everything is already as you suggested. The token seems fine too. The SESSION_DOMAIN is currently null as per my config/session.php settings

If your live server uses HTTPS,check this "SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=true" (or)  Verify that the "VerifyCsrfToken" middleware is active in the kernel (or)  check that the directory permissions for storage/app/public/files/uploads. Did you use storage link? (or) Make sure the storage directory permissions are set correctly (storage/framework/sessions) if you're using file-based sessions (SESSION_DRIVER=file).

I edited the answer, you can try that method, but it is not recommended because you are skipping the csrf token validation.

I tried setting the SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE to true but no results. The thing is I am already using this same exact method for something else on my server which accesses another folder in the storage directory to view and delete and that works with no errors.
